# Is this diagram from Uniswap's documentation correct?

Tags: uniswap

Denote respectively **rA** and **rB** the reserve of Token **A** and Token **B**. Let f = 1 - fee (*i.e.* 0.997) and **x** be the input amount. Then the price function of Uniswap v2 for a pair (**A**, **B**) is

**P**(x) = (**rB** * x * **f**)/(**rA** + x * **f**)

[This answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/89985/66540) explains well how the source code computes it:
the computation is based upon the preservation of the "constant product formula": **rA** * **rB** = **k**, where **k** is a constant. In other word, the product of the new reservers is the same as the old: **rA'** * **rB'** = **rA** * **rB** = **k**. But this seems to contradict the [documentation of Uniswap v2](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/protocol-overview/how-uniswap-works/) which says that

> In practice, Uniswap applies a 0.30% fee to trades, which is added to reserves. As a result, each trade actually increases **k**.

Moreover, the answer seems to suggest that the new reserves are **rA'** = **rA** + x * **f** and **rB'** = **rB** - **P**(x).
I was rather confused when I have seen the diagram below from the documentation.

[image]

Here are my questions:

1. If **k** actually increase at each trade, then why the price is computed in such a way (*i.e.* based on preservation of **k**) ?
2. What should be the value of **rA'** on the diagram? Let x = 3, **rA** = 1200, then by the computation above,  **rA'** = **rA** + x * **f** < 1203. It looks like that the illustration  has multiple errors:

   - It says that the fee is 0.03%, but it should be 0.3%
   - It doesn't agree whether **rA'** is 1203.03 or 1203.3. But both are wrong either way.
3. What the "price" in blue on the diagram actually means ? (why it doesn't use **P**(x) ?)

Comment: The schema was definitely wrong and is now fixed. It still doesn't explain how calculations are made though, and contains misleading information. For instance, the 3% fee applies in the contract to the traded amount (amountIn), while the schema implies that the fee should be used to calculate the traded amount. Not a reliable source of info for someone who wants to dive in.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteMartin I moved on since then, but thanks for your comment.